# Network issue in vsat

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet, multicast, satellite

In my server-client architecture, I **multicast** 100 MB files to many clients from server via satellite link. Network traversal is through 5 hops.  I have the 10Mbps ( i.e. 1250 Kilo Byte per second ) bandwidth link.

When I multicast the first file to many client, first hop get the incoming speed is of ~9.0 mbps but the receiver end get the speed of only ~4.2 mbps. All clients are 10mb half duplex.

I can see, there is low network usage; But I don't know where exactly.
If server is sending at the speed of ~9.0 mbps, then client should got the same speed.

I am using the reliable UDP for multicasting.

Is there any way to find out, what is the incoming and outgoing bandwidth usage of each hop (for a particular port.) ?
Is there exist any tool/utility/application who can serve the purpose.

All the hops are at remote location, so that going over there is not possible.

Comment: Does your company own and operate the 5 hops in question, or do these hops belong to a different services provider?

Comment: Belong to third party

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Tools

> Is there any way to find out, what is the incoming and outgoing bandwidth usage of each hop (for a particular port.)?

Unless you own the network element, or your third-party WAN provider discloses the information, you can only *estimate* end-to-end available ingress and egress bandwidth along a network path.  See below.

> Is there exist any tool/utility/application who can serve the purpose.

- For path "available bandwidth estimation" that I mentioned above, you should review [Sally Floyd's archive of end-to-end TCP/IP bandwidth estimation tools](http://www.icir.org/models/tools.html).  I am most familiar with [`yaz`](https://bitbucket.org/jsommers/yaz/wiki/Home), which is based on unicast UDP packets.
- To see whether you are dropping packets at any given router hop (which is your bottom-line problem), you can use [`mtr`](http://www.bitwizard.nl/mtr/); there is also a [`win-mtr`](http://winmtr.net/) client, which supports Windows.  To see a simple example of how I typically troubleshoot packet drops, [see my answer on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/433244/77053).  This technique is most effective at providing visibility to packet drops at the first point where they happen (since `mtr` doesn't give much visibility to downstream drops beyond that point until you correct the first).

A simple technique to get a rough estimate of where your drops are is to install [`mtr`](http://www.bitwizard.nl/mtr/) on your server and then run an [`mtr`](http://www.bitwizard.nl/mtr/) session to trace packet loss to a single multicast client while you are transferring your 100M file.  For more precise measurements you could use [`iperf`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf/) to saturate the network instead of your 100M file (as long as you coordinate WAN downtime appropriately with other groups in the company).

### Diagram

The rest of my answer is going to use the following diagram for reference:

[image: Mcast_problem]

In the diagram:

- R1 through R5 are IP routers
- S1 and S5 are ethernet switches
- The blue server on 172.16.1.0/24 represents your multicast server.
- C51 through C55 are examples of multicast receivers (could be any number of receivers)

The specifics of the WAN between R1 and R5 usually won't matter much, we just need a baseline topology so we're on the same page.

From what I can tell, you're saying that R1's interface on 172.16.1.0/24 shows about 9Mbps while you are sending the 100MB file and R5's interface on 172.16.5.0/24 shows about 4.2Mbps when clients are receiving via reliable UDP multicast.  When you say reliable, I assume that means there is some kind of packet sequencing built into the multicast service, and the client application knows how to request a retransmission from the server.

### Diagnosis

If this description is correct, there are a few likely causes:

1. Link congestion somewhere after R1, as you asserted in your question.
2. Performance limitations of any Rx device in the path, including R1 and R5 (such as hitting a multicast replication performance limit)
3. You're hitting a throughput limitation of 10M half-duplex ethernet.

Causes 1 or 2 would be revealed by using [`mtr`](http://www.bitwizard.nl/mtr/).  However, cause 3 is worthy of a bit more discussion.  10M/half links provide a maximum of 10Mbps for a *unidirectional* transfer.  If you are sending bi-directional traffic on a 10M/half link, you will typically see substantially less than 10Mbps because of ethernet's [CSMA/CD dynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier_sense_multiple_access_with_collision_detection).  On a half-duplex link, ethernet cannot simultaneously transmit and receive; if stations try to do this, their frames will collide, and both stations will delay retransmission for a random time.

I test networks for a living.  When I have tested effective bi-directional throughput of 10M/half links, I generally see between 3Mbps and 4Mbps.  The numbers you're sharing above sound very similar.  I don't have enough evidence to make an accusation, but I would not be surprised if your 10M/half links are the problem; particularly if the link between R5 and S5 is 10M/half.

Comment: Thanks Mike for this detailed answer. There are few things, which I had forgot to mention:

1. Server to client, the bandwidth link is of 10Mbps
2. Client to server, the bandwidth link is of 256kbps only

3. Reliable UDP protocol which I am using here is UFTP. <http://www.tcnj.edu/~bush/uftp.html>
This protocol gives the acknowledgement for every packet, which it received at client side

4. Server is Windows 7 and client is LINUX

Comment: I am curious, what was the solution to your problem?

Comment: No, I have not found any solution yet. But just given bounty to you. If you have any further thought on the same, please share it.

Comment: The above link for UFTP is stale.  It is now located at http://uftp-multicast.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can remotely access (and have a privileged account on) each machine, you might try the `iftop` utility.

Something like `iftop -f udp -F "port <port> and host <previous hop>"` should give you all udp traffic from the given host on the given port. See the man pages for more info on constructing filters. (Also of note: assuming you have access to the network, you can also monitor the entire network by specifying the network/netmask like so: `-F 10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0`)

If you don't want to / can't install iftop, but have access to iptables you can also have it log your traffic and use that to calculate bandwidth.

First setup a chain for your application and forward all incoming / outgoing traffic:

`iptables -N $CHAIN && iptables -A FORWARD`

Then setup a rule for separate upload / download:

```
# Downloads
iptables -A FORWARD -d $PREVIOUSHOP -j $CHAIN

# Town A Uploads
iptables -A FORWARD -s $PREVIOUSHOP -j $CHAIN`
```

Now view the traffic usage for each chain: `iptables -L -v -n`

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to each hop as they belong to third party.  So can not install iftop nor use iptables.

Comment: Yah, sorry, realized that was probably what you meant shortly after posting.